# Ajax time interval call to a php function

Tags: php, ajax

I have an ajax code that calls a php file:

```
function ajaxRequest(){
var requestData; 

try{
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    requestData = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
    // IE
    try{
        requestData = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            requestData = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e){
            // Your browser is brokeded.
            alert("Please try again later!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
// Send/receive data
requestData.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(requestData.readyState == 4){
        document.getElementById("testDiv").innerHTML = requestData.responseText;
    }
}
requestData.open("GET", "tester.php", true);
requestData.send(null); }
```

What I actually want the code to do is to call a php function on the same page at time intervals. I intend to display a notification with it on adding a new row to a table in a mysql database. Please, help me edit this code or probably a new one if the above is not okay. I will appreciate the help. Thank you

Comment: What about putting this function in a setInterval ?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to use jQuery, which is a js framework that offers several functions. An example of your code would be this:

```
        function callMe()
        {
            $.ajax({
                   type: "GET",
                   url: "test.php",
                   data: "id=1",
                   success: function(response){
                              $("#testDiv").html(response);
                            }
           });
        }

    // Call it
    setInterval(callMe, 5000); //every 5 secs
```

Comment: will the code need an external library or will it work that way? Thanks.

Comment: You just need jquery. Download the main file and include it in your page as js script.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
       function callMe()
        {
            $.ajax({
                   type: "GET",
                   url: "count.php",
                   data: "id=1",
                   success: function(response){
                              $("#Count").html(response);
                            }
           });
        }

    // Call it 
    // "setInterval" means every 5 secs 
    // "setTimeout" just once...

    setInterval(callMe, 5000); 
</script>  

<p>Count:<span id="Count"></span></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer! While a code snippet could answer the question it's still great to add some addition information around, like explain, etc ..