# setInterval with php code

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, setinterval

I wanted to make a "friend request" option on my website and I would like if friend requests can be displayed as soon as possible. (even if I don't reload page)
So what I've read here I need `setInterval` and Ajax, I found the code, and it works perfect for the first time, but it doesn't refresh on database changes. Is that intended or am I doing something wrong?
Example, I have 2 friend requests, and I get one more friend request while my page is idle, and it doesn't shows up, even tho my javascript is doing the query again, right?
I know I shouldn't use `mysql_query`, and I will fix that as soon as possible, but no way that could be the problem.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var ajax_call = function() {
    document.getElementById('js_hack').innerHTML = "<?php 
    $ses_sql3=mysql_query("select * from friend_request where reciver='$login_username'", $connection);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($ses_sql3);
    if($num_rows > 0) { echo $num_rows; }?>";
    };

    var interval = 1000 * 1; // where X is your every X minutes

    setInterval(ajax_call, interval);
});
```

Comment: That code does not include an AJAX call at all. Just naming the function `ajax` does not make it AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your `<?php?>` code in a separate file, and call that file.

I didn't look at the rest of your code to validate that it is "good", thought.

You can't have serverside code perform on the client side, like that; nor do you want it to.

Here is an example, and what looks to be a dupilcate question: [Ajax time interval call to a php function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756816/ajax-time-interval-call-to-a-php-function)

Answer (score 0):

When a client executes that php script on your site, the database is analyzed only once then after that, every "interval" ms, the html element with the ID of js_hack will always be rewritten with the same value.

Do some research on The XMLHttpRequest Object:

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp

When you are done, make a php file that contains the data you're trying to set innerHTML to, then make a function in javascript that uses the xmlhttprequest functionality to open and process that newly created php file.